# Vim Regex substitute question

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I'm trying to replace in VIM all multiple "-" characters (from the start of lines) with "="

p.e. replace "-----" with "====="
or replace "----------" with "=========="

I created this regex:

```
%s/^-\{2,}/=  ????/g
```

Does anyone know how I can replicate the "=" substitution?
(what do I have to put after "=")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s/^-\{2,}/\=substitute(submatch(0), '-','=','g')/
```

or:

```
:%s/^-\{2,}/\=repeat('=',len(submatch(0)))/
```

See `:help sub-replace-\=` for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's a better answer, but practically speaking, I would do this as two separate operations just for simplicity:

```
%s/--/==/g
%s/=-/==/g
```

First replace all double occurrences, which would turn `-----` into `====-`. Then fix the leftovers (`=-`) using the second. I would love to see the more elegant answer, though, if it is possible to do.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, `%s/-/=/g` does the job, but on the entire file, in every `-`.

If the lines you want to substitute do start with `-` I'd do it this way:

```
g/^-/s/-/=/g
```

Or, if you have some space before the first `-`:

```
g/^\s*-/s/-/=/g
```

---

The remaining problem arrives in lines like this:

```
----------- the-composite-word
```

They turn into:

```
=========== the=composite=word
```

To solve that, there are many ways. I not that master to suggest a very general way, but this may work for dashes between words:

```
g/^-/s/\w\@<!-/g
```